# Text centering after a line break within a TextView field

Tags: android, xml

I have been doing my homework on this one, but all the suggestions I have come across do not seem to be working. I am new to android applications and although the answer may be simple to some, I just cannot see where I am going wrong....

I have a TextView field that contains a string value with a line break (\n). On the graphical output, the lower line of text is not centered to the TextView container. My code is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:text="@string/maxText"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My string is as follows:

```
<string name="maxText">My text part 1:\nMy text part 2</string>
```

The lower line of the outputted text is aligned left to the container, but I require it in the center. I have tried all the suggestions that I have come across in forums, etc - but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated on this.

Answer (score 2):

Actually we don't need to put that text into two textviews.

Either set the `android:layout_gravity="center"` for the layout containing the textview in the XML file.

If this doesn't work.

Try setting the gravity center for a layout params and set this params to the Layout programatically. Like below.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
yourLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
yourLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

This worked for me.

Hope this will work fine for you too. :)

Answer (score 1):

The only sensible way to solve this is to create two text views, with the second one immediately below the first and is set to `android:layout_gravity="center"` and  `android:gravity="center"`

Comment: Thanks, Neoh. Kinda thought that. Just thought it would have been nice to add a small snippet of code somewhere instead of another TextView container....

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code in your class, I use it for buttons and it is working well, both lines are centered. I guess it should work the same for a `TextView`:

```
String styledText = "My text part 1" + "<br />" + "My text part 2";         
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(styledText));
```

NOTE: so you will have to declare separatly the 2 strings and get them from the Resources

Comment: Didn't work for me. Tried even with <center> tags. What worked for me is setting text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); every time the TextView is updated via code.

Answer (score 0):

The best possible way in xml is to add the property

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```